# Q: Mid-2009 15" MBP Line-out / Headphone-out jack not working properly - how to resume behaviour without replacing Logic Bus?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, hardware, headphones

I'm in the unenviable position of having a pretty maxed out Mid-2009 15" MacBookPro (1TB SSD+8Gb memory), and I've been getting almost 6 years of continuously decent behaviour out of it...

Except...

The line-out / headphone-plug jack has never been amazingly solid.

And in the last week or so, I've started experiencing behaviour where even if I plug in a cable, OS X or the hardware might not recognise that the cable is plugged in, so I will sometimes be stuck with laptop speaker output only.

Are there tricks that I could use / try out to make the plug "work better"?

Unfortunately, Apple just discontinued mid-2009 15" MBP Logic Bus manufacturing / sales - so I cannot dish out the 700Eur to get the Logic Bus replaced at repairs.

Comment: did you ever clean it ? as they tend to get clogged with stuff.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD How would you recommend cleaning it? :) Like a safe method or something?

Comment: First use tooth pick and try to remove anything in there. next use q-tip soaked in alcohol and swipe in there to clean the contacts.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD I think that would qualify as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be amazed what can collect in the headset socket over the years, hindering its proper functioning. Giving them an occasional good cleaning will keep them running.

First, use a tooth pick and try to remove anything that could be stuck in there.

Next use a q-tip soaked with alcohol and swipe in there to clean the contacts.